# Unable to build project output group 'Content Files from Web (Active)

Tags: msbuild

I got below error in MS build.

WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' in path 'C:....\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\'
ERROR: Unable to build project output group 'Content Files from Web (Active)'

Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Error resolution in below URL https://stackoverflow.com/a/71494016/12544418

Answer (score 0):

This error came up because my workspace wasn't upto date. I did get force (Get specific version) and rerun the build, it worked !! Posting it may helpful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

In your project expand all the Folders and see if there are any files missing with yellow alert symbol.If you delete them,you can build your application as normally.